# How to create a generic React component with a typed context provider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With React's new context API, you can create a typed context producer/consumer like so:

```
type MyContextType = string;

const { Consumer, Producer } = React.createContext<MyContextType>('foo');
```

However, say I have a generic component that lists items.

```
// To be referenced later
interface IContext<ItemType> {
    items: ItemType[];
}

interface IProps<ItemType> {
    items: ItemType[];
}

class MyList<ItemType> extends React.Component<IProps<ItemType>> {
    public render() {
        return items.map(i => <p key={i.id}>{i.text}</p>);
    }
}
```

If I instead wanted to render some custom component as the list item and pass in attributes from `MyList` as context, how would I accomplish that? Is it even possible?

---

What I've tried:

#### Approach #1

```
class MyList<ItemType> extends React.Component<IProps<ItemType>> {
    // The next line is an error.
    public static context = React.createContext<IContext<ItemType>>({
        items: []
    }
}
```

This approach doesn't work because you can't access the class' type from a static context, which makes sense.

#### Approach #2

Using the standard context pattern, we create the consumer and producer at the module level (ie not inside the class). The problem here is we have to create the consumer and producer before we know their type arguments.

#### Approach #3

I found [a post on Medium](https://medium.com/@nicolas.schabram/thanks-for-the-article-that-was-helpful-861454c1d06f) that mirrors what I'm trying to do. The key take away from the exchange is that we can't create the producer/consumer until we know the type information (seems obvious right?). This leads to the following approach.

```
class MyList<ItemType> extends React.Component<IProps<ItemType>> {
    private localContext: React.Context<IContext<ItemType>>;

    constructor(props?: IProps<ItemType>) {
        super(props);

        this.localContext = React.createContext<IContext<ItemType>>({
            items: [],
        });
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <this.localContext.Provider>
                {this.props.children}
            </this.localContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

This is (maybe) progress because we can instantiate a provider of the correct type, but how would the child component access the correct consumer?

---

#### Update

As the answer below mentions, this pattern is a sign of trying to over-abstract which doesn't work very well with React. If a were to try to solve this problem, I would create a generic `ListItem` class to encapsulate the items themselves. This way the context object could be typed to any form of `ListItem` and we don't have to dynamically create the consumers and providers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know TypeScript so I can't answer in the same language, but if you want your Provider to be "specific" to your `MyList` class, you can create both in the same function.

```
function makeList() {
  const Ctx = React.createContext();

  class MyList extends Component {
    // ...
    render() {
      return (
        <Ctx.Provider value={this.state.something}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Ctx.Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  return {
    List,
    Consumer: Ctx.Consumer 
  };
}

// Usage
const { List, Consumer } = makeList();
```

Overall I think you might be over-abstracting things. Heavily using generics in React components is not a very common style and can lead to rather confusing code.

Comment: I agree that his approach was an over-abstraction. It's almost a benefit of React that it makes this difficult which ends up encouraging a more appropriate solution. Thanks for the response.

Comment: How would a descendant component of `List` access the context `Consumer`? Would the `Consumer` itself need to be passed down the component tree as a prop? That feels slightly counter intuitive since contexts help avoid plumbing a bunch of props down a deep tree.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and I think I solved it in a more elegant way: 
you can use `lodash once` (or create one urself its very easy) to initialize the context once with the generic type and then call him from inside the funciton and in the rest of the components you can use custom useContext hook to get the data:

## Parent Component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { once } from 'lodash';

const createStateContext = once(<T,>() => React.createContext({} as State<T>));
export const useStateContext = <T,>() => useContext(createStateContext<T>());

const ParentComponent = <T>(props: Props<T>) => {
    const StateContext = createStateContext<T>();
    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={[YOUR VALUE]}>
            <ChildComponent />
        </StateContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

## Child Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStateContext } from './parent-component';

const ChildComponent = <T>(props: Props<T>) => {
     const state = useStateContext<T>();
     ...
}
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Looks like a cool answer, but where is `State` coming from in third line, as `State<T>`?

Comment: This is a very elegant solution! I like it a lot!

Comment: @brandonscript - I thought the same thing. It's the model for the Context so you should already have a type that you can slot in there.

Answer (score 7):

### I think the answer, unfortunately, is that the question doesn't actually make sense.

Let's take a step back; what does it mean for a Context to be generic? Some component `Producer<T>` that represents the Producer half of a Context would presumably only provide values of type `T`, right?

Now consider the following:

```
<Producer<string> value="123">
  <Producer<number> value={123}>
    <Consumer />
  </Producer>
</Producer>
```

How SHOULD this behave? Which value should the consumer get?

1. If `Producer<number>` overrides `Producer<string>` (i.e., consumer gets `123`), the generic type doesn't do anything. Calling it `number` at the Producer level doesn't enforce that you'll get a `number` when consuming, so specifying it there is false hope.
2. If both Producers are meant to be completely separate (i.e., consumer gets `"123"`), they must come from two separate Contexts instances that are specific to the type they hold. But then they're not generic!

In either case, there's no value in passing a type directly to `Producer`. That's not to say generics are useless when Context is at play...

### How CAN I make a generic list component?

As someone who has been using generic components for a little while, I don't think your list example is overly abstract. It's just that you can't enforce type agreement between Producer and Consumer - just like you can't "enforce" the type of a value you get from a web request, or from local storage, or third-party code!

Ultimately, this means using something like `any` when defining the Context and specifying an *expected* type when consuming that Context.

#### Example

```
const listContext = React.createContext<ListProps<any>>({ onSelectionChange: () => {} });

interface ListProps<TItem> {
  onSelectionChange: (selected: TItem | undefined) => void;
}

// Note that List is still generic! 
class List<TItem> extends React.Component<ListProps<TItem>> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <listContext.Provider value={this.props}>
                {this.props.children}
            </listContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

interface CustomListItemProps<TItem> {
  item: TItem;
}

class CustomListItem<TItem> extends React.Component<CustomListItemProps<TItem>> {
    public render() {
        // Get the context value and store it as ListProps<TItem>.
        // Then build a list item that can call onSelectionChange based on this.props.item!
    }
}

interface ContactListProps {
  contacts: Contact[];
}

class ContactList extends React.Component<ContactListProps> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <List<Contact> onSelectionChange={console.log}>
                {contacts.map(contact => <ContactListItem contact={contact} />)}
            </List>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### Check how Formik dose it

For me it was important to check types when using context (useContext) just like Formik useFormikContext.

#### Example of generic type

```js
type YourContextType<T> = { state: T; setState: (s: T) => void }
```

#### Create context (do not care about type)

```js
const YourContext = createContext<YourContextType<any>>(
  undefined as any,
);
```

#### Context hook with generic type

```js
function useYourContext<T>() {
  const context = useContext<YourContextType<T>>(YourContext);


  if (context === undefined) {
    // assert if context is available
    throw new Error('No context provided');
  }

  return context;
}
```

#### Use hook

```js
 const { state, changeState } = useYourContext<{ name: string }>();
```

You will see state and changeState have types. Maybe it is not in 100% what you are looking for but for me it was enough. Check @TheRubberDuck explanation

src: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/packages/formik/src/FormikContext.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Generic type arguments work just fine in Context API props, with a little bit of coaxing. The main issue is that when initializing the Context, you don't yet know what the "narrowest" type will be, so you need to use a wider one, such as `any`.

Then, when setting the value via `Provider`, you can use the more narrow type. However, as of writing this, this won't transfer the narrow type to the consumers. To make that work, you'll simply need to provide the type again to `useContext`.

Example:

```js
type MyNarrowType = {a: number, b: string};
type MyContextProps<T> = {data: T};

const MyContext = createContext<MyContextProps<any>>({
  data: {},
});

function MyProvider(props: {data: MyNarrowType}) {
  const value: MyContextProps<MyNarrowType> = {data};
  return <MyContext.Provider><MyComponent /></MyContext.Provider>
}

function MyComponent() {
  const {data} = useContext<MyContextProps<MyNarrowType>>(MyContext);
  // data is now a MyNarrowType
}
```

It's not ideal, but I think it works well enough for most situations.